# implode comma after each name

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the below shortcode:

```
function authors_shortcode($atts)
{
    $recipe = Recipe::init($id);

    $defaults = [
        'after'  => '',
        'before' => '',
    ];

    if (empty($recipe->get_authors())) {
        return 'SacFoodies';
    }

    $atts = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts, 'authors');

    $output = [];

    $output[]  = sprintf( '<span %s>', genesis_attr( 'entry-author'));
    $output[] .= $atts['before'];

    foreach ($recipe->get_authors() as $profile) {
        $output[] .= sprintf( '<a href="%s" %s>', $profile->get_url(), genesis_attr( 'entry-author-link' ));
        $output[] .= sprintf( '<span %s>', genesis_attr( 'entry-author-name' )) . $profile->get_name() . '</span>, ';
    }
    $output[] .= '</span></a>' . $atts['after'] . '</span>';

    $output[] .= implode(', ', $output);

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('authors', 'authors_shortcode');
```

That gives me an output of my custom post type profiles as such:

[image]

I've manually added a comma after the  call, but how can I make it where the comma doesn't appear at the end? I've used `implode(', ', $param)` before but that was when it was an array, how can I make adjustments to the below code to just get a comma between?

Comment: I think you want this: https://3v4l.org/7GjCT

Comment: @Nick, that worked perfectly! I'll give you an up vote on the other post. Update: Looks like it was deleted, please make a update so I can give you the credit

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. The dupe wasn't mine but if one of those answers is useful you can upvote it.

Comment: @Nick, all done :)